# refresh the table in android

Tags: android

In my android application i am using a table with scrollview.I am giving the user a service suchthat if the user clicks on a row and say delete the row gets deleted from the table.But after this deletion i want the table to get refreshed and load only the fresh data from database.

Could anyone please let me know how can i refresh the table or refresh the page in android?

Please share your valuable suggestions .

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I achieved it by calling the intent again for the same page.

Comment: There is a much better way, see Thorstenvv's answer.

Answer (score 2):

Call your adapter's notifyDataSetChanged() when items have been changed, added or deleted.
Call notifyDataSetInvalidated() when all data is gone.

Comment: How about an example... new to Android?!